# How to run raspberry pi imager in old windows computer without OpenGL 2.0 or with ANGLE Open GL ES?

Tags: raspberry-pi-imager

[image: Imager Error msg]

After installing Imager, it is failed to start showing the above error message. I have failed to find "ANGLE Open GL ES 2.0 emulation libraries" mentioned in the error message.

My spec: windows 7, core 2 duo, gigabyte g31m es2c main board, no external gpu.

Comment: If you like any answer (including the existing answer), please accept the answer by clicking on the green check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Error-Failed-to-create-OpenGL-context-for-format-QSurfaceFormat-when-launching-Fusion-360.html

1. In window menu, search for "environment variables".
   or go to my computer > properties > Advanced system settings > environment variables
2. in lower portion "system variables"
3. click on "new", use
   variable name   = QT_OPENGL
   variable value  = angle
   click ok.
   [image: variable entry window]
4. again create a new entry
   variable name   = QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM
   variable value  = warp
   click ok
   [image]